# What "category" are proper names of this kind "Debbie Downer", "Negative Nancy" etc?

Tags: terminology, proper-nouns

I need some umbrella term for those funny names like "Debbie Downer", "Negative Nancy", "Realistic Rita", "Chatty Cathy". Could I say that they are examples of figurative language?

Comment: They're a type of epithet.

Comment: There seems to be an obvious case of alliteration but no other figurative elements. Are there examples of these that are not alliterative?

Comment: Thanks Gaston.                                              Dominik there are some e.g. Average Joe, Plain Jane.        But would't you say that all nicknames and namecalling are intristically figurative. I mean considering the figurative/literal division they for sure are not literal. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a linguistics question. It might get better answers on English Language & Usage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any figurative element here either. *"Negative Nancy"* is perceived as having a negative attitude to many things, quite literally. These nicknames may be exaggerations, but that doesn't make them figurative.

A figurative nickname would be *"Thunderstorm Thomas"* to describe an irate person. Thomas is not actually a thunderstorm, but has some quality (compared to other people) that is likened to some quality of a thunderstorm (compared to normal, calm weather).

And as Dominic pointed out, your examples are alliterative - The alliteration makes these nicknames just more catchy.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends as some examples, eg. 'Doubting Thomas' have quite clear cultural semantic origins, so are not figurative.

Answer (score 0):

I may late responding, but I think you were looking for the "Explanatory Style"... Which basically is a category for the sub categories : Optimist, Pessimist or Realist.

- Positive Polly
- Debbie Downer
- Realistic Rita